# Tenancy - Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, multi-tenant

Im trying to test the Tenancy functionality via PHP Unit test but there are errors coming out.

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use in /var/www/database/migrations/tenant/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php on line 54
```

I already test the migration but there is a different when running on unit test.
This error only appear when creating the Tenant.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

PHP7+
Tenancy 3

Comment: give a (different) namespace to your new class CreateUsersTable. It was devised for this purpose.

Comment: It seems like, it only works on phpunit test, but when you run the application or while creating tenancy not in unittest it will cause error the Some class does not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when doing migration and creating a tenant at the same time, so my solution is, create a migration first then do the unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it happened because there was one pre-existing class.

So, it might be solved by selecting the correct class and deleting one of the class.

Comment: No, There are totally 2 classes exists because the migrations are being copied on tenant folder, well this error only occurs on unit testing :)